# unresolved symbols for the constructor and other member functions while writing unit test using google test framework

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

There is library say myLib in my myLib.vcproj
It has class

```
namespace mylibtuils{

    struct DefaultHander: IHandler
    {

         DefaultHander():_mV1(0),_mV2(1), _mv3(4){  
         }
         ~DefaultHander(){}
    protected:
         int _mV1,_mV2, _mv3;
         bool _mflag1;
    public:
         void updateSettings(wstring xmlSourceFile);
    };

}
```

I need to write unit test using google test framework. So I created another project myLib_UT.vcproj adding references to gtest, and mylib
it has a simple code

```
GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Running main() from gtest_main.cc\n");
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}

TEST(updateSettingstestcase, Positive)
{
    mylibtuils::DefaultHander _handler;

    wstring xmlSourceFile(L"D:\\testfile.xml");
    _handler.updateSettings(xmlSourceFile);
    ASSERT_TRUE(xmlSourceFile != L"");
}
```

when I build it says unresolved symbols for the constructor.

Is it not possible to test if the classes are in a seperate dll? 
I could just add all the files to my unittest project but I would end endup adding files that myLib depends on.

Please advise how I can resolve this

Comment: Of course you can test classes from different libraries in google test. Can you please specify what kind of error did you get exactly?  Unfortunately, from the code you provided I cannot deduce anything. Can you please try to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Generally speaking, I would recommend against identifiers that begin with an underscore.  They are [reserved by the implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) in a bunch of situations and it's simply easier to avoid any conflict by not beginning any identifier with an underscore.

Comment: Make sure you implement all methods and that symbols needed outside the DLL are exported.